# MySQL table not updating no errors

Tags: php, mysql

I have this little block of PHP code used to update a SQL table. However, it should, because right now it's not doing anything, nor is it producing any errors:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `wordpress`.`thor_members` ($key) VALUES('$_POST[$key]') WHERE ID = '$_POST[ID]'";
var_dump($sql);
mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $sql);

if(mysqli_error($conn)){
    var_dump(mysqli_error($conn));
}
```

The `var_dump` actually prints MySQL lines that work perfectly fine if I run them into PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: Updating table with `INSERT INTO`?

Comment: `$_POST[ ID ]`?? missing quotes around `ID`

Comment: We use `mysqli_query()` to execute the query

Comment: although it is insert query, your missing quote around id, in this line ` ID = '$_POST[ID]'"` second you are not executing query. third var_dump sql is useless. it does not work like that.

Comment: @arif_suhail_123 - You don't need quoutes around numbers in a SQL query and I'm guessing the `var_dump($sql)`is for dumping the concatenated query, which do work like that. But yes, `mysql_real_escape_string()`doesn't run your query. It actually shoul make your whole sql-query useless in the way it's used here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$keyVal = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST[$key]);
$id     = intval(mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['ID']));
// I'm assuming $_POST['ID'] is an int?    

$sql    = "UPDATE `wordpress`.`thor_members` SET $key = '$keyVal' WHERE ID = $id";

mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if(mysqli_error($conn)){
    var_dump(mysqli_error($conn));
}
```

This should work.

If $key comes from an unknown source, you should escape that too but id you set that in your own code before, this should be enough.

However, you should really look up prepared statements instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "UPDATE `wordpress`.`thor_members` 
       SET ".$key."='".$_POST[$key]."' WHERE ID = '".$_POST["ID"]."' ";
mysqli_query($sql);
```

Try this way

Comment: How you use `where` condition in INSERT query

Answer (score 0):

A variation on a theme.

```
<?php
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `wordpress`.`thor_members` ( `$key` ) VALUES ( '".mysqli_real_escape_string( $conn, $_POST[ $key ] )."' ) WHERE `ID` = '".mysqli_real_escape_string( $conn, $_POST['ID'])."'";
    var_dump( $sql );

    $result=mysqli_query( $conn, $sql );
    if( $result ){
        /* yeay - all good */

    } else {

        /* bogus */
        if( mysqli_error( $conn ) ){
            var_dump( mysqli_error( $conn ) );
        }   
    }
?>
```